# Second soap call to self made soap server makes apache produce a segfault

Tags: php, apache, soap, wsdl, segmentation-fault

Hi everyone I'm cracking my head over this for two weeks already.

The problem is that I made a soap service which seems to work alright. When I ask it to show it's functions it returns them all etc. But when I try to invoke two functions to the server I get an segfault error:

'[notice] child pid 13950 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)'

But when I invoke the two functions seperately they work. I googled for this for a week and tried different wsdl formats but the only thing that came up was a possible php bug or some error in the wsdl (which seems unlikely because my validator can't find errors).

The browser gives me this in response:

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

I'm currently running php version 5.3.6 and also tried 5.2.17 to try to eliminate the possible php bug. But they both gave the same error.

Nobody over here at the office knows how to fix this because 'everything should be alright'.
Could anyone get me in the right direction?

The client:
(this code gives the apache crash)

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
try{
    $soap = new SoapClient("http://localhost/virtueleincasso.wsdl", array("exceptions" => 1));
    $password = $soap->virtuele_incasso_login('user', 'pass');       
    $status = $soap->get_status($password , 1060);
}catch (SoapFault $exception){
    echo $exception->faultstring;
}
```

The server:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
$server = new SoapServer(DIR_ROOT."/virtueleincasso.wsdl");
$server->setClass('PP_Api');
$server->handle();
die();
```

**SOLUTION:** I used a die function to stop the server function returning an empty string. I fixed it by changing this to an exit function.

Comment: Apache segfaults? Time for p/strace, isn't it? Launch it in a debugger and take a look what exactly happens.

Comment: Going to try that. New to this p/strace thing. Googling now.

Comment: I'd try on a separate machine too, in case there's something awry with the server you're getting this on.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with multiple PHP processes using the soap extension. It seems to be a bug in the way WSDL caching is handled. I also tried disabling it with `ini_set()` calls as you have without success. I eventually found a workaround in my case. I needed to set the `cache_wsdl` option to `WSDL_CACHE_NONE`.

```
return new SoapClient("http://localhost/virtueleincasso.wsdl", array(
    "exceptions" => 1,
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
));
```